# Can't inspect boxed properties while debugging Rust

Tags: rust

I am currently going down the Rust rabbit hole and implemented a tree that uses `Box<T>` for allocating memory on the heap. I then tried to run a debugger to inspect the properties of a tree struct in order to see wether its structure is correct.

Unfortunately I am not able to see what is inside the `left` and `right` boxed properties within the debugger. I tried Jetbrains CLion with the Rust plugin, Jetbrains RustRover and VS Code with the rust-analyzer and CodeLLDB plugins as described in many guides.

Am I missing something or doing it wrong? Many thanks in advance!

The code I am working on:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

fn main() {
    let mut tree = Tree::new(5);

    tree.add_node(Tree::new(3));
    tree.add_node(Tree::new(7));
    tree.add_node(Tree::new(2));
    tree.add_node(Tree::new(6));

    Tree::print_tree_in_order(&tree);

    tree.add_node(Tree::new(9));
}

struct Tree {
    value: i8,
    left: Option<Box<Tree>>,
    right: Option<Box<Tree>>,
}

impl Tree {
    fn new(value: i8) -> Box<Self> {
        Box::from(Tree {
            value,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        })
    }

    fn print_tree_in_order(tree: &Box<Tree>) {
        match &tree.left {
            Some(subtree) => Tree::print_tree_in_order(subtree),
            None => {},
        }

        println!("{}", tree.value);

        match &tree.right {
            Some(subtree) => Tree::print_tree_in_order(subtree),
            None => {},
        }
    }

    pub fn add_node(&mut self, node: Box<Tree>) {
        match self.value.cmp(&node.value) {
            Ordering::Greater | Ordering::Equal => {
                match &mut self.left {
                    Some(subtree) => { subtree.add_node(node); }
                    None => { self.left = Option::from(node) }
                }
            }
            Ordering::Less => {
                match &mut self.right {
                    Some(subtree) => subtree.add_node(node),
                    None => self.right = Option::from(node),
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just `Debug` print the thing?

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of a debugger.

Comment: Are you sure you use a debug build?

Comment: Yes. The breakpoint pauses code execution and I am able to see scopes, stack, etc.

Comment: What are you seeing inside the fields? Or are you seeing no fields at all?